# Read data form mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone I am trying to write a PHP code that reads the information from my database, unfortunately I got the following error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: numcontrat in C:\wamp\www\test\crud-php-simple-master\crud-php-simple-master\index.php on line 46 and 
>        Notice: Undefined index: dnotification in C:\wamp\www\test\crud-php-simple-master\crud-php-simple-master\index.php on line 51

I share with you my source code:

```
<?php`

    //including the database connection file
    include_once("config.php");

?>

<html>
    <head>  
        <title>Homepage</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="add.html">Add New Data</a><br/><br/>    
        <table width='80%' border=0>    
            <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>       
                <td style="background-color:#57D251; "> <b>&nbsp; N Contrat</b></td>
                <td style="background-color:#57D251; " ><b>&nbsp;Avenant</b></td>
                <td style="background-color:#57D251; " ><b>&nbsp;Discription</b></td>
                <td style="background-color:#57D251; " ><b>&nbsp;Fournisseur</b></td>
                <td style="background-color:#57D251; " ><b>&nbsp;Delai</b></td>
                <td style="background-color:#57D251; " ><b>&nbsp;Date de notification</b></td>
                <td style="background-color:#57D251; " ><b>&nbsp; Date envigyeur</b></td>
                <td style="background-color:#57D251; " ><b>&nbsp;Date de fin caution</b></td>
                <td style="background-color:#57D251; " ><b>&nbsp;Avance forfaitaire</b></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            //fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
            $sql= 'SELECT * FROM contrats ';
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            if (! $result){
               echo('Database error: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            echo $result;     

            while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc  ($result)) {        
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" .$res['numcontrat']."</td>"  ;
                echo "<td>" .$res['avenant']."</td>"   ; 
                echo "<td>" .$res['discription']."</td>"   ; 
                echo "<td>" .$res['fournisseur']."</td>"   ; 
                echo "<td>" .$res['delai']."</td>"   ; 
                echo "<td>" .$res['dnotification']."</td>"  ;
                echo "<td>" .$res['denvigyeur']."</td>"  ; 
                echo "<td>" .$res['dcaution']."</td>"  ; 
                echo"<td>" .$res['aforfaitaire']."</td>"  ; 
                echo "<tr>";

                //echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";     
            }        
        ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

thank you for your answer

Comment: These fields in array must be in  contrats table

Comment: the problem persists, and i have the same error : Undefined index: numcontrat in C:\wamp\www\test\crud-php-simple-master\crud-php-simple-master\index.php on line 46

Comment: can you send your table structure?

Answer (score 1):

According to your exception, **dnotification** column doesn't exist in your table **contrats**.

Create this column in your Database table and then try.

In your Comment you have mentioned

> //fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
>
> $sql= 'SELECT * FROM contrats ';

But it will fetch in the order it is stored.To fetch in descending order, Use query something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM contrats order by id DESC
```

where id is the autoincremented field.